# keras custom function won't eval/compile/fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I'm trying to use the following (custom) loss function to train a keras neural network:

y_pred and y_true are arrays of length 40.
Say y_true is 0 everywhere except on the jth component where it is equal to 1, 
write y and z for y_true and y_pred resp. then:

blank">
{i<40}(|i-j|+1)\cdot(y_i-z_i)^2" title="boostSquare(y,z)=\sum_{i<40}(|i-j|+1)\cdot(y_i-z_i)^2" />

Here's the code I intended to use :

```
import keras.backend as K
def boost_square(y_true, y_pred):
    w = K.constant(np.array([[np.abs(i - j) + 1 for i in range(40)] for j in 
                            range(40)]), dtype=np.float64)
    return K.sum(K.transpose(w * y_true) * K.square(y_true - y_pred))
```

Running this works and prints 2.25 as expected :

```
y_true = np.array([int(i == 2) for i in range(40)])
y_pred = np.array([0.5 * int(i < 2) for i in range(40)])
print(K.eval(boost_square(y_true, y_pred)
```

Yet, this fails to compile with the following error message :

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
input_layer = Input(shape=(40,), name='input_layer')
output_layer = Dense(units=40, name='output_layer')(input_layer)
model = Model([input_layer], [output_layer])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=boost_square, 
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

> TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type float64 of argument 'x'.

Since I'm stubborn, I also tried this, which didn't fix anything and might hinder performance :

```
def boost_square_bis(y_true, y_pred):
    z_true = K.cast(y_true, np.float64)
    z_pred = K.cast(y_pred, np.float64)
    w = K.constant(np.array([[np.abs(i - j) + 1 for i in range(40)] for j in 
                   range(40)]), dtype=np.float64)
    boost = K.transpose(w * z_true)
    boost = K.cast(boost, dtype=np.float64)
    square = K.square(z_true - z_pred)
    square = K.cast(square, np.float64)
    ret = K.sum(boost * square)
    return K.cast(ret, dtype=np.float64)
```

What am I missing? Where does this error come from?

### Solution 1

**Credits to AnnaKrogager** : the dtype of w wasn't compatible with the model. The
model compiles when one defines :

```
def boost_square(y_true, y_pred):
    w = K.constant(np.array([[np.abs(i - j) + 1 for i in range(40)] for j in 
                            range(40)]), dtype=np.float64)
    return K.sum(K.transpose(w * y_true) * K.square(y_true - y_pred))
```

## Iteration 1

Now, the model compiles but won't fit, I get this error message (128 is the batch_size) :

> ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 40 and 128 for 'mul_2' (op: 'Mul') with input shapes: [40,40], [128,40].

My custom loss function behaves oddly with respect to this first axis indeed,
this code will raise the very same error :

```
fake_input = np.random.rand(128,40)
fake_output = np.random.rand(128,40)
print(K.eval(boost_square(fake_intput,fake_output)))
```

## Iteration 2

As AnnaKrogager pointed out, it is more consistent to use a proper np.dot than * followed by a transposition (that messes with batch axis). So I came up with this new definition of boost_square :

```
def boost_square(y_true, y_pred):
    w = K.constant(np.array([[np.abs(i - j) + 1 for i in range(40)] for j in 
                              range(40)]), dtype=np.float32)
    return K.sum(K.dot(w, y_true) * K.square(y_true - y_pred))
```

But this triggers following when I try to **fit** the model :

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_shape'

Hence, I tried

```
def boost_square(y_true, y_pred):
    w = K.constant(np.array([[np.abs(i - j) + 1 for i in range(40)] for j in 
                             range(40)]), dtype=np.float32)
    return K.sum(K.dot(K.dot(w, y_true), K.square(y_true - y_pred)))
```

And got a brand new error message \o/ :

> Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [40,40], In[1]: [32,40]

## Definitive Solution

**Credits to AnnaKrogager**

### Ingredients

1. Use proper matrice product K.dot ratter than * .
2. Though w was meant to be applied to y_true, don't use K.dot(w,y_true) since
   it messes with the batch axis. Ratter, use K.dot(y_true,w) and transpose to have matching shapes.
3. If you want to test the loss function with np.arrays, say y_true and y_pred, make sure you recast them as K.constant.

Here's the **code** :

```
def boost_square(y_true, y_pred):
    w = K.constant(np.array([[np.abs(i - j) + 1 for i in range(40)] for j in
                range(40)]), dtype=np.float32)
    return K.sum(K.dot(K.dot(y_true, w), K.transpose(K.square(y_true - 
                                                              y_pred))))
```

And for the test :

```
y_true = K.constant(np.array([[int(i == 2) for i in range(40)]], 
                             dtype=np.float32))
y_pred = K.constant(np.array([[0.5 * int(i < 2) for i in range(40)]], 
                    dtype=np.float32))
print(K.eval(boost_square(y_true,y_pred)))
>>2.25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your model outputs `float32` whereas the constant `w` inside your loss function is of type `float64`. You can fix this by simply changing the data type of `w`:

```
def boost_square(y_true, y_pred):
    w = K.constant(np.array([[np.abs(i - j) + 1 for i in range(40)] for j in 
                            range(40)]), dtype=np.float32)
    return K.sum(K.transpose(w * y_true) * K.square(y_pred))
```

**Answer to your second question:** If you multiply tensors in Keras it means that the tensors get multiplied element wise, hence they must have the same shape. What you want is the matrix product so you should use `K.dot(y, w)` instead of `w * y`.

Comment: Great thanks. 

K.eval works too once I set the dtypes of y_true and y_pred to float32, hence everything is fine :)

Comment: I have edited my answer with an answer to your new question

Comment: Yes, using K.dot(w, y_true) makes sense to me. Now keras.backend.dot throws me 

>AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_shape'

Comment: When running `K.eval()` you mean? You should pass tensors and not numpy arrays to the function. Try converting your arrays to tensors with `K.constant(array)`.

Comment: I got this message while compiling the model as well as when running K.eval

Comment: I am able to run the code with no problems. Maybe double check (only compiling, no K.eval).

Comment: You need to use `K.dot()` also when multiplying with `K.square(y_pred)`. And you should not convert to tensor inside the loss function (as the loss function already expects tensors as input). If you want to test the loss function with `K.eval()` then pass it as input `K.constant(fake_input)` and `K.constant(fake_output)` instead of numpy arrays.

Comment: I am indeed able to run the code. Compiling the model isn't the problem indeed, it's fiting it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188395/discussion-between-olivier-roche-and-annakrogager).